# Obter rows de no mínimo 3 dias atrás

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com coluna `datetime` e preciso obter os resultados que já tenham 3 dias de existência, todos com mais de 3 dias, tentei usar

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM tb WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Porém não deu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu `where` deve ser:

```
WHERE DATE(date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CompareDateWithOffset.sql).