# Função para filtrar dados de uma tabela por data

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

Possuo uma tabela no banco de dados e preciso fazer uma função para filtrar pela data. Quero buscar os registros de uma data que já passou e que me retornasse os registros da tabela do banco como estavam naquele dia e que eu possa editar estes dados em uma outra página. Estou fazendo em php "puro" sem Framework e no padrão mvc. **Obs:** Já possuo um select que me traz os dados do banco em uma página, só preciso de uma função e saber como trago estes dados do banco de outro dia e que possa ficar selecionada a data no topo da página, sendo possível que seja selecionada qualquer data e que me mostre os registros da data selecionada nesta página.

**O que preciso ?**

Exemplos práticos de como fazer está função citada acima.

Comment: Como está a estrutura da tabela? O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: [buscar data 7 dias antes da data actual php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26976/91), 
[Consultar dados de 1 dia á 3 dias atrás mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56888/91) e 
[Obter rows de no mínimo 3 dias atrás](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46946/91)

Comment: Meu caso é outro. Minha tabela faz um backup dela mesma as 00:00 todos dias só atualizando a coluna da data para o novo dia e duplicando os registros. Ela mantem os registros de ontem, só altera a data. Precisaria fazer uma consulta encima dessa coluna data. Se for dia 10, me traz os registros do dia 10. Pois tenho uma função que edita estes dados, sendo assim todos dias serão modificados e criara um backup as 00:00.